# Method name of object _chart failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a `Run Time error 1004 :Method name of object _chart failed` while I try to name my chart. Sometimes this runs, and sometimes it doesn't. Here is the part that causes the error, (the whole macro is really long, so I haven't posted it all.)

**Drawing a 3D col chart of the histogram:**

```
Range("U1:R23").Select
    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlCylinderCol
    ActiveChart.Name = "mcChart" -----------> Error
With ActiveChart
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Dynamic Weight Chasing Histogram" & Chr(10) & "Local SWT ,File:" & Name & ", Roadforce-Check Spin" & Chr(10) & "assembly after dimensions changed, Old software"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "weights(Oz)"
Charts("mcChart").SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Array(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, "4-5", "5-6", "6-7", "7-8", "8-9", "9-10")
.SeriesCollection([4]).Interior.Color = RGB(139, 0, 0) ' dark red
.SeriesCollection([3]).Interior.Color = RGB(205, 92, 92) 'indian red
.SeriesCollection([2]).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 0, 128) 'magenta
.SeriesCollection([1]).Interior.Color = RGB(144, 238, 144) 'light green
End With
```

Please let me know if you can find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you modify your code and see if it works?

```
dim newChart as Chart

Range("U1:R23").Select
Set newChart = Charts.Add

With newChart
   .ChartType = xlCylinderCol
   .Name = "mcChart" & Format(now, "hhmmss")

   'setting other properties
End With
```

Comment: Doing so gives me another runtime error 1004 : "Cannot rename a sheet as another sheet, a reference object library or a workbook reference by visual basic". I am sure that there are no sheets called mcChart in my workbook.

Comment: Set the `.Name = "mcChart" & Format(Now, "hhmmss")` and let me know if it fails. My guess is, the code is adding charts (when the macro runs) and tries to give same name for every chart, which could be failing. And the charts are overlapping each other, so you are unable to see the charts behind the current one.

Comment: This code is adding chart *sheets*, which require unique names, like any worksheet object, so your suspicion is confirmed. The 1004 error raises if the sheet name already exists.  **Note:** An ordinary `ChartObject.Chart` does not require a unique name.

Comment: Well this adds the time stamp to the chart name and it doesnt give an error, but regarding giving the same name to every chart, I am breaking the macro before if goes to the other charts. So my original error happens in the first chart itself. Is there a way to not put the time stamp in this. Other Programs are reading these charts and naming them something else, messes will all that, also the time stamp changes everytime I run this code, which will changed the name too, which makes this another hassle. Thank you though.

Comment: I understand the concern of this chart name existing, that was one of the first things I checked, when I run the macro, all the previous charts are deleted, hence the chart sheet named "mcChart" doesnt exist. I want to name the newest chartsheet as mcChart.

Comment: @AnishChakrabarti: I am not able to understand your point. However, as suggested by David, make sure that there isn't a chartsheet with the same name, delete the sheet (if it is present).

Comment: my point is that I checked David's concern, and there are no chartsheets present with the same name

Comment: @AnishChakrabarti: I dont know why the error would occur then. Close this workbook, reopen, run the macro. If the error occurs the 1st time, there has to be the sheet.

Comment: well reopening it worked...I was sure there were no other charts with the same name....I hate mondays. Thank you !

Comment: @AnishChakrabarti: I don't know the reason of why things work at times and why that thought came to my mind. I am glad that it is fixed.

Comment: I think that is the most annoying, painful answer to any computer/IT/programming related issue.  "Turn it off and turn it back on again".  I hate giving it, but tragically, it so often is the case that it works. <hangs head> :-(